# Searching on server side with Axios for multiple parameters using one text input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to be able to search through multiple parameters in an Axios get request using only one text field.

Right now I've created a state for filters as an array, and I use the split method on the input value to create an array, but after that I'm stuck. I can't manage to make the search flexible enough.

**This is the API Call**

```
export const fetchData = (id, filtered, pageSize, page, sortBy) => {
    let searchQueryParamString = "ID=" + id.toUpperCase() +
        "&parameter1=" + getFilterValue(filtered[0]) + 
        "&parameter2=" + getFilterValue(filtered[1]) + 
        "&parameter3=" + getFilterValue(filtered[2]) +
        "&PageSize=" + pageSize +
        "&PageNumber=" + 0 +
        "&SortBy=" + sortBy;

    return axios.get(endpointUrl + searchQueryParamString, config).then(
        response => {
            return response.data;
        }
    ).catch(error => { return null; });
}

const getFilterValue = (filtered) => {
    let filterValue = null;
    if(filtered != null) {
        filterValue = filtered;
    }
    return filterValue != null ? filterValue : '';
}
```

**This is the code for my search input and for fetching the data**

```
fetchData = (state) => {
     this.setState({ loading: true });
     this.requestData(state.pageSize, state.page, state.filter, state.sorted).then(
         res => {
             this.setState({ data: res.rows, pages: res.pages, selectedRow: 0, loading: false });
         }
     );
}
handleSearch = (e) => {
    const filter = e.target.value.split(' ');
    this.setState({ filter }, this.fetchData());
}
```

What I want is to be able to search for any combination of those 3 parameters, worth mentioning that the data is shown in an Ant Design Table and I also don't have access to the back-end.